# Voice-Over not working for attributed string UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, uitextview, voiceover

```
func configureTextView() {
    textView.isSelectable = true
    textView.isEditable = false
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: Subscription.smsPriceDisclaimer)
    if let range = Subscription.smsPriceDisclaimer.range(of: Subscription.termsOfUse), let url = URL(string: AppURL.Shop.URL.termsOfUse) {
        attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: url, range: Subscription.smsPriceDisclaimer.nsRange(from: range))
    }
    
    if let range = Subscription.smsPriceDisclaimer.range(of: Subscription.privacyPolicy), let url = URL(string: AppURL.Shop.URL.policiesAndDisclosures) {
        attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: url, range: Subscription.smsPriceDisclaimer.nsRange(from: range))
    }
    
    if let range = Subscription.smsPriceDisclaimer.range(of: Subscription.noticeOfFinancialIncentive), let url = URL(string: AppURL.Shop.URL.noticeOfFinancialIncentive) {
        attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: url, range: Subscription.smsPriceDisclaimer.nsRange(from: range))
    }
    
    // Set the 'click here' substring to be the link
    let textAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: Style.Color.universal_757575,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: UMAStaticFont.dealCardDescriptionNS)
    ]
    attributedString.addAttributes(textAttributes, range: NSMakeRange(0, Subscription.smsPriceDisclaimer.count))
    textView.linkTextAttributes = [
        .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue
    ]
    textView.delegate = self
    textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    textView.attributedText = attributedString
}

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    if interaction == .invokeDefaultAction, URL.scheme?.starts(with: "http") ?? false {
        let start = textView.text.index(textView.text.startIndex, offsetBy: characterRange.location)
        let end = textView.text.index(textView.text.startIndex, offsetBy: characterRange.location + characterRange.length)
        let range = start..<end
        let titleVal = String(textView.text[range])
        delegate?.showWebview(urlString: "\(URL)", titleValue: titleVal)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

As there are 3 attributed links inside textview on running accessibility inspector links are not accessible separately. can someone suggest how to make voice-over working.